# Firefox WebIDE debugger tab blank when remotely debugging an android device

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I can connect to my device fine, I can see console and inspects the pages, but whenever I try to open the debug tab in the WebIDE it remains blank.

I connect to my android device using USB ADB, the debugger feature used to work until all of the sudden it went blank whenever I tried accessing it.

I have tried reinstalling firefox on both my computer and my android device but to no avail.
What could be causing this?

After some looking around I found an exception that may be related in the Main Process console:

```
error occurred while processing 'listWorkers: TypeError: 
Ci.nsIWorkerDebugger is undefined Stack: 
onListWorkers@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> 
resource://devtools/server/actors/tab.js:48:87 
onPacket@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> 
resource://devtools/server/main.js:141:212 
_onJSONObjectReady/<@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> 
resource://devtools/shared/transport/transport.js:25:166 
exports.makeInfallible/<@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> 
resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:2:467 
exports.makeInfallible/<@resource://devtools/shared/base-loader.js -> 
resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:2:467 Line: 48, 
column: 87
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the WebIDE itself. So, first of all, you should check if you can reproduce the problem on [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org) using a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). If it does, you should file a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools:%20WebIDE) for it. If you cannot reproduce it there, it may either already be fixed or it's related to some browser preference you have set in your normal profile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but it went away when I switched to Firefox Nightly *on Android*. Desktop version (stable, beta or nightly) does not appear to matter.